# preg_match lazy?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hey guys I'm trying to strip out the last _1.jpg if it 
exists in my expression, but I am having some trouble

Scenarios are like follows.

`image_name_1.jpg (should be image_name.jpg)`

`image_name_1_1.jpg (should be image_name_1.jpg)`

I came up with this, but it seems to be returning null

`$pic = ($pic[strlen]-6 == '_') ? preg_replace('/*.\_[0-9]/', '.jpg', $pic) : $pic;`

What's wrong with my formula? Could someone help?

Comment: just use str_replace once to replace "_1.jpg" to ".jpg"

Comment: what if its _2 though, or _4 or _9 this isn't limited to a single integer hence the `[0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strrpos` along with **ohaal**'s expression:

```
$pic_name=(strrpos($pic,'_',-6)) ? preg_replace('/_\d\.jpg$/','.jpg',$pic) : $pic;
```

Link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 3):

`*.` makes here truble. You can use `*.?` - the `?` mean lazy quantification.

But your expression havent to pattern whole input string, only target - see ohaal's answer.

Comment: This questions over a year old now =)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
preg_replace('/_\d\.jpg$/', '.jpg', $pic);
```